# Do not send value from form Angular

Tags: angular, rest, http, webpack, promise

Is there any possible way to not sending value from form to server?

I have update Request and in this function I don't want to send hospital.name (I tried to set it to null but it's doesn't work as I want.)

Is there any way to Ignore this value?

```
      update(hospital: Hospital): Promise<Hospital> {
    const url =`${this.hospitalsUrl}/${hospital.id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(hospital), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => hospital);
  }
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(hospital.id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is to create a new object to send to the server.

For example to update hospital, you can create an UpdateHospitalRequest, and a converter from the form to the UpdateHospitalRequest that can be used in your HospitalService.

This will make sure that even if you change your form for some reason, the request will always be the same unless you decide to change it.

Answer (score 2):

```
update(hospital: Hospital): Promise<Hospital> {
delete hospital.name;
    const url =`${this.hospitalsUrl}/${hospital.id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(hospital), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => hospital);
```

**delete hospital.name;** will remove property from Object.

```js
var myObject = {
    "name": "muthu",
    "id": "123",
    "password": "abc-123"
};
delete myObject.password;

console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update(hospital: Hospital): Promise<Hospital> {
hospital.name=‘’;
    const url =`${this.hospitalsUrl}/${hospital.id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(hospital), {headers: this.headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(() => hospital);
```

Try this